# detect enter event while mouse is pressed javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

How can i detect that mouse entered a node while mouse is pressed?

Example: I pressed with left mouse button on pan, Then entered a circle placed in the pan. If i try to detect that the mouse entered the circle it can not be detected.

```
pane.setOnMousePressed(e -> System.out.println("Pressed"));
c.setOnMouseEntered(e -> System.out.println("Entered"));
```

c is circle object placed on the pane. If mouse pressed and i enter to circle "Entered" does not appear.

How can i overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onMouseDragEnteredProperty But also see the discussion on different drag modes at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: Try it, post an update to your question with your attempt (and specifically what didn't work about it) if you can't make it work.

Comment: I try this: On detect drag event i set full drag on pane and then used dragentered event on the circle. But it does not work for me.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can't tell what's wrong with your implementation unless you [edit] your question with an actual example (a [MCVE]).

Comment: OH, I was do something wrong. I was using drag entered event which is wrong, I need mouse drag. It worked, Thanks i'll update my post with solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) helped solving this issue.

Solution:

When draging the pane we will register the general drag event and start full drag from this pan. Next we will use mouse drag entered event on the circle to detect if the drag entered to circle or not.

```
pane.setOnDragDetected(e -> pane.startFullDrag());
c.setOnMouseDragEntered(e -> System.out.println("Solved :)"));
```

That's it.

Comment: You will need to add `c.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Solved :)"));` if you want to trigger single click too